# Tree Structure for SharePoint synced files on desktop

Tags: synchronisation

I synced my SharePoint folders to my computer so I can view them on my desktop. Is there a way to see a expandable/collapsible tree structure view of my SharePoint folders that does not require coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you synced a SharePoint document library, then you should see it in your Windows explorer as an expandable tree:

[image]

I think, the problem is that that these icons are located in the "favorites" category of Windows Explorer. This category does not expand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unlike in your screenshot, in my Windows explorer, I don't have the arrows to the left of my SharePoint folders allowing me to expand/collapse the folder. I do have them for the folders that are actually kept on my computer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you send a screenshot, please? What version of Windows are you using? Are you using WEBDAV protocol or the actual OneDrive for business sync client?

Comment: I had to post an answer in order to upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see, the folders circled in black are on my computer and have arrows I can use to expand/collapse them. The SharePoint and OneDrive folders do not. I'm running Windows 7 Professional and I'm using the actual OneDrive for business sync client. Thank you for your time! (And sorry for posting as an answer - can't upload images in a comment.)

Comment: Interesting. I think, the problem is that that these icons are located in the "favorites" category of Windows Explorer. This category does not expand. I've dragged "SharePoint" there on my PC and I have the same thing. There has to be a completely separate "SharePoint" category that is not present on your screenshot... The question is why it's missing.

Comment: Or maybe I'm too used to Windows 8.1 and 10 and think it's normal there. Maybe that's a limitation of Windows 7?.. I don't have Windows 7 anywhere to test this

Comment: Perfect! I dragged the icon out of the Favorites category and dropped it onto my Desktop and now it will expand/collapse. You were right - the problem is that I was opening it through the Favorites category. Thank you!